# Exception by Android Studio on startup

Tags: java, exception, sdk, startup

I installed Android SDK along with the IDE yesterday (the complete package). I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

However when i launched it today and created a project , the SDK showed an error whose details are given below. I did my best in searching for any question with a similar problem. Sorry for the shabby formatting. Is something in my system not compatible with the code in SDK (SDK is searching for something during initialization and is unable to find it?) ?

```
button doesn't exist 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0
    at java.awt.event.InputEvent.getMaskForButton(InputEvent.java:247)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.isMouseGrab(Container.java:4486)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4511)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:778)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1614)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1571)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.show(DynamicWizard.java:511)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:304)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)



java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0
    at java.awt.event.InputEvent.getMaskForButton(InputEvent.java:247)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.isMouseGrab(Container.java:4486)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4511)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:778)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1614)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1571)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.show(DynamicWizard.java:511)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:304)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: r u got answer? I am also same problem

Comment: I get this error even just with the Android Studio sitting open. It hasn't broken anything so far. I'm not sure why it's happening though.

Comment: Similar thing is happening with me. But it hasn't affected anything so far.